# System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.' data grid

Tags: c#

When I run the application it displays no errors. After I load the datagridview from MySql and press the button that leads to the above function it displays error.

[image: Error]

```
int SMSLineID = 0;
List<SendMessageWebSerrvice.WebServiceSmsSend> SendDetail = new List<SendMessageWebSerrvice.WebServiceSmsSend>();
{
    string MessageBody = string.Empty;
    long MobileNo = 0;
    bool IsFlash = false;
    foreach(DataGridViewRow dataGridViewRow in dgvShowUsers.Rows)
    {
        DataGridViewCheckBoxCell Checking = dataGridViewRow.Cells["colSelect"] as DataGridViewCheckBoxCell;
        if (Convert.ToBoolean(Checking.Value) == true)
        {
            MessageBody = "User of " + dataGridViewRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString() + " " + dataGridViewRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString() + " " + txtMessage.Text;
            MobileNo = Convert.ToInt64(dataGridViewRow.Cells[3].Value);
            IsFlash = false;
            SendDetail.Add(new SendMessageWebSerrvice.WebServiceSmsSend(){
                MessageBody = MessageBody,
                MobileNo = MobileNo,
                IsFlash = IsFlash
            });
        }
    }
}
if (!int.TryParse(txtLineSerial.Text, out SMSLineID)) throw new Exception("Error");
SendMessageWebSerrvice.SendReceive WS = new SendMessageWebSerrvice.SendReceive();
string Message = null;
long[] Result = WS.SendMessage(txtUserName.Text.Trim(), txtPassword.Text.Trim(), SendDetail.ToArray(), SMSLineID, null, ref Message);
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Message)) throw new Exception(Message);
MessageBox.Show("OK");
return;
```

My grid view phone number is 3 .

Comment: Please do not post images of code. Often they are unreadable and unusable to cut and copy your code to test it. Anyway if you get that error on that line then your cell doesn't contain something that could be converted to a int64.

Comment: I update my post

Comment: Try `dataGridViewRow.Cells[3].Value.Trim()`

Answer (score 1):

Please do not post image. About your problem, because your input have some character isn't a number so system can't parse it. You should use this approach instead of the current:

`Int64.TryParse($"{dataGridViewRow.Cells[3].Value}", out long value);`

Comment: I just update the answer, please try again with that. It can avoid error if your value is null.